# Using pre-annotated dataset to do NER on a custom entities in the IBM Cloud

Tags: dataset, ibm-cloud, named-entity-recognition

I've been searching the documentation for a way to use a pre-annotated dataset to do NER on a custom entities in the IBM Cloud.
I haven't been able to find a way to do it. 
Is it something that is possible to do with Watson Knowledge Studio and/or Natural Language Understanding ?
Can you point me toward the right ressources ?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can train your customized model with Watson Knowledge Studio. [See Adding documents for annotation](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/services/watson-knowledge-studio?topic=watson-knowledge-studio-documents-for-annotation) for the format of pre-annotated documents you can import to WKS.